# Flutter lost connection to device when using Firebase.initializingApp()

Tags: flutter, windows, firebase

I'm currently working on a simple authentication application using Firebase Auth in Flutter for windows. When I tried to create the firebase instance using Firebase.initializingApp() and debugged, the debugger print "Lost connection to device" and exit. It worked normally when I removed the Firebase.initializingApp().
I'm currently using firebase_core ^2.16.0 and firebase_auth ^4.10.1.
Is there anyone undergone this situation? Can you recommend how to solve this problem? Thank you.

```dart
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await windowManager.ensureInitialized();

  Firebase.initializeApp(
          name: "[DEFAULT]", options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.options);

  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

I want the application to run normally.

Comment: `Firebase.initializeApp()` should be enough.

Comment: I tried and it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Comment: I tried this to, it didnt work either. I'm using Flutter to create a Windows application, but 'flutterfire configure' command but the 'Windows' platform is not in configuration options (only have: web, ios, android and macos). So I have to create a custom DefaultFirebaseOptions with only essential params like apiKey, appId, messagingSenderId and projectId. It still didnt work